# setPosition does not update on iphone safari browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, safari, firebase

I have a html page that uses Firebase to get updated geolocation data. that data is then used to update a marker in a google map. The map works fine (map renders, and markers move accordingly) in the chrome browser on a laptop, but when I visit the same link on my iphone safari browser, I do not receive the updated marker positions.

In the iphone Safari browser, the map renders, displays the start marker, destination marker, and the current position marker. But when firebase it is time to fire off a current position marker change, nothing happens.

I know the location data is accurate,and being sent, as it works on the laptop. but for some reason, the setPosition function does not seem to be firing correctly on the mobile browser. Below is the relevant javascript. I left out user specific information just because...well, this is the internet. Would anyone have an idea as to why setPosition doesnt update the currentPosition Marker when being displayed in mobile devices?

```
 <script>
    var styles1 = code omitted for simplicity

    var map;
    var userLocationMarker;
    var userDestinationMarker;
    var HakiFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://leftOutOnPurpose");
    var WMBHakiFirebaseRef;
    var user;

    function initialize(){
        this.initMap();
        if (isWatchMyBackClient()) {
            uuid = getClientUuid();
            setFirebaseData(uuid);
        }

    }

    function initMap(){
        styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles1, {name:"Blizzard Haki"});
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.864716, 2.349014),
            // center: LatLng, //should be firebase longLat
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'blizzard_style']
            }
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('wmbMap'), mapOptions);
        //Associate the styled map with the map type id
        map.mapTypes.set('blizzard_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('blizzard_style');
    }

    /**********************/
    /*  HELPER FUNCTIONS  */
    /**********************/
    function isWatchMyBackClient(){
        //check for a uuid in the header
        var query = window.location.search;

        if (query.indexOf("?") !== -1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getClientUuid(){
        var uuid = "";
        var queryUrl =  window.location.search;
        uuid = queryUrl.slice(1);

        return uuid;
    }

    function setFirebaseData(uuid){
        WMBHakiFirebaseRef = HakiFirebaseRef.child("WMB").child(uuid);
        WMBHakiFirebaseRef.once("value", function(userdata){
            user = userdata.val();
            if(userdata.val() !== null){
                setUserMarker(userdata.val());
                setDestinationMarker(userdata.val());
                watchUser();
            } else {
                console.log("Could not get user data")
            }
        });
    }

    function setUserMarker(userData){
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: userData.latitude, lng: userData.longitude});
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "starting location"
        });
        var greenPin = '/images/green-pin.png';
        var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'starting Location',
            icon: greenPin
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'click', function() {
           infoWindow.open(map,markers);
        });

    }

    function setDestinationMarker(userData){
        var infoWindowd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "My Destination"
        });
        var destpin = '/images/destpin.png';

        destMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(userData.dest_latitude,userData.dest_longitude),
            map: map,
            title: 'My Destination',
            icon: destpin
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(destMarker, 'click', function() {
           infoWindow.open(map, destMarker);
        });
        destMarker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindowd.open(map, destMarker);
        });
    }

    function watchUser() {
        WMBHakiFirebaseRef.on('value', function(userData) {
            user = userData.val();
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(user.latitude,  user.longitude);
            var destLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(user.dest_latitude,  user.dest_longitude);
            updateUserMarker(latLng);
            updateDestinationMarker(destLatLng);

        });

    }

    function updateUserMarker(latLng){
        if(!userLocationMarker) {
            var image = '/images/currLocBtn.png';
            var userInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Current Location'
            });
            userLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                title: 'Current Location',
                icon: image
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(userLocationMarker, 'click', function() {
               userInfoWindow.open(map, userLocationMarker);
            });
        }
        //update info window here later
        userLocationMarker.setPosition(latLng);
    }

    function updateDestinationMarker(destLatLng){
        destMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });
        destMarker.setPosition(destLatLng);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Here's a link of related issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679639/google-maps-api-v3-marker-setposition-not-working-in-safari-sencha-touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v figured out what the issue is. After further testing, I realized that the Marker did indeed update, as long as my App was running in the foreground. Meaning, when I would switch from my app, to the mobile safari browser, my application would stop sending geolocation data to the firebase database, and the marker would not receive any new information - giving the impression that it never moved.

However, when I triggered the geolocation from the mobile app from my phone, and then accessed the above website from my wife's mobile safari, the marker did indeed move.

The solution is for me to allow my app to run geolocation tasks in the background.

Thank you @leroy Thompson for all of your support and follow-up with this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a cache issue, use a random key to refresh after every update.

```
var k = Math.random();
var HakiFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://leftOutOnPurpose?k="+k);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! The HakiFirebaseRef value comes from a specific URL that holds my firebase database. would adding a randomly generated key cause any issues when resolving the correct url? 

And if it does resolve, should I get a new ref. to the cloud Database every time the person moves?

Comment: ok I think too many listeners are being added to the same instance again and again. Do this.
google.maps.event.clearListeners(userLocationMarker, 'click');
google.maps.event.addListener(userLocationMarker, 'click'.....{}

userLocationMarker is a global variable defined at the top and events are stacking on it.

PS. I haven't used firebase before...

Comment: No need to get a new ref... the *?* symbol is a query that browsers use for inline variables, Is it updating after all?